# How to calculate the same number by avoiding the sign?

Tags: sas

I have a SAS column as below

```
-10
 20
-30
 40
```

I want to make the column like

```
10
20
30
40
```

I need to remove the sign and keep the same number. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ABS** function.

A small sample code:

```
data begin; 
  input var @@; 
  cards; 
1 1 -1 -1 2 -2 -3 3
; run;

data wanted; 
  set begin; 
  var2= abs(var);
run;
```

For more on abs see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0mv8rmj37a6kln1ue7a1fip6rbc.htm)

EDIT: In case you are dealing with strings you can just remove the string:

```
data begin; 
  input var $ @@; 
  cards; 
1 1 -1 -1 2 -2 -3 3
; run;

data wanted; 
  set begin; 
  var2= tranwrd(var, '-', '');
run;
```

Also documentation on [TRANWRD](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000215027.htm)

Answer (score 1):

two ways without creating additional variables:

```
data begin; 
input var @@; 
cards; 
1 1 -1 -1 2 -2 -3 3
; run;

data wanted; 
set begin; 
var= abs(var);
run;

proc sql noprint;
create table wanted2 as
select abs(var)as var from begin;quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to be to create a new variable where var2=sqrt(var**2)